# Override VueJS component methods from another component

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I've tried to override VueJS component method from another component.

Here I want to override `checkForm` method from another VueJS file.

inside ./src/components/auth_form.vue:

```js
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  props: {...},
  methods: {
    checkForm: function(e: any) {
      console.log('Please override this method!')
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

I want to override this method from ./src/views/signup.vue:

```js
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
import authForm from '../components/auth_form.vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'signup',
  components: {
    authForm
  },
  data: function() {...}, 
  methods: {
    // This does not override the method above!
    checkForm: function(e: any) {
      console.log("success")
      // Reset the form
      this.signupForm = {} as SignupForm
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they will not override because the 2 functions are in 2 different scopes. They can have same name and works independently. In order to do what you want, you have to put the checkForm function of `auth_form` inside its props.

So in `auth_form`:

```
props: {
  checkForm: {
    type: Function,
    default(e) {
      console.log('Please override this method!')
    }
  }
}
```

then when calling it in `signup.vue`

```
<auth-form :check-form="checkForm" />  //pass parent's method into children props

methods: {
  checkForm() {
    console.log("success") // this will override the default one
  }
}
```